# SQL Server / PowerShell: bulk Insert Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

My code in Powershell:

```
Function AutoImportCommaFlatFiles($location, $file, $extension, $server, $database)
{
    $full = $location + $file + $extension
    $all = Get-Content $full

    $columns = $all[0]
    $columns = $columns.Replace(" ","")
    $columns = $columns.Replace("|"," ] VARCHAR(100), [")

    $table = "CREATE TABLE " + $file + " ([" + $columns + "] VARCHAR(100))"

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $buildTable = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $insertData = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

    $connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + $server + ";Database=" + $database + ";integrated security=true"
    $buildTable.CommandText = $table
    $buildTable.Connection = $connection

    ## Added to function
    $x = 0
    $insertData.CommandText = "EXECUTE stp_CommaBulkInsert @1,@2"
    $insertData.Parameters.Add("@1", $full)
    $insertData.Parameters.Add("@2", $file)
    $insertData.Connection = $connection

    $connection.Open()
    $buildTable.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $connection.Close()

    ## Added to function
    $x = 1

    if ($x = 1)
    {
        $connection.Open()
        $insertData.ExecuteNonQuery()
        $connection.Close()
    }
}
AutoImportCommaFlatFiles -location "C:\Users\XXXX\Test3\" 
     -file "Illinois" -extension ".csv" -server "XXXXX" -database "TEST"
```

My SQL code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE stp_CommaBulkInsert
    @file VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @table VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @f VARCHAR(MAX), @t VARCHAR(MAX), @s VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @f = @file
    SET @t = @table

    SET @s = 'BULK INSERT ' + @t + '
              FROM ''' + @f + '''
              WITH (
                      FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',
                      ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0A'',
                      FIRSTROW = 2
                   )'

    EXEC sp_executesql @s
END
```

My error

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2, column 1 
>   (ID ).
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 3, column 1 (ID ).
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 4, column 2 (BusinessName ).
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 5, column 1 (ID ).
>   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>
> The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"."
>   At C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\AutoUpload.ps1:29 char:9
>   +         $insertData.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

I have tried changing the Delimiter settings, I have tried changing the Column Data type settings, I have tried removing info from the ID column, I have tried filling in spaces with NULL and have had no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the code you do a `if ($x = 1)`. The `=` in PowerShell is an assignment where i think you want to test if the value of $x is 1. Change that into `if ($x -eq 1)`

Comment: I figured it out. SQL was not altering the procedure even though I was using the Alter command. Had to go into the procedure and tell it to make an alter to query